# Immigration at USA airports

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit

I am flying through American Airlines from Tokyo to Los Angles via Dallas airport.
I want to ask where I have to clear my immigration? Dallas or Los Angles?

Answer (score 9):

Dallas.

[**At what point during a traveler's trip to the U.S. does a traveler clear U.S. Customs and Border Protection?**](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/458/~/when-does-a-traveler-clear-u.s.-customs-and-border-protection)

> If the final destination is in the U.S. and the first port of arrival
>   is in the U.S., travelers must clear immigration and customs at the
>   first port of entry. If a connection is involved, the traveler will
>   not be required to go through another clearance when they arrive at
>   their final destination

.

Comment: Except for the last sentence, this is true regardless of whether the final destination is in the US.

Answer (score 1):

At the airport you land/enter first.
So for you this would be at the Dallas airport.